# In crystal reports, I would like to count the number of occurances for a set of values

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

We have a particular drug that comes in different strengths. In my crystal report I'd like to display the number of times a given strength occurs in a dataset (planned treatments for patients). For example:

```
Strength  Occurances 
500       2
600       5
700       0
800       7
```

How could I easily do this?

Comment: You should give us the database structure and some data examples linked to the schema to help us with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You would required a formula to count.

create a formula like below

```
if {mytable.field} = 'xxx' then
 {mytable.field};
```

then

```
count({formula});
```